# I would like to get specific character when i click on a character in metro richtextedit in c#

Tags: asp.net, windows, c#-4.0

For example, lets say may edit text have following text
1,2,3,4,5,6

If I click on any of the number i.e. 5, it should call a method with a value "5" as input.

Comment: Please, add some relevant code you have up to now.

Comment: Is this windows forms or asp.net ? Kindly add code example

Comment: windows form application

Comment: private void richTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

this method is called when i click on my text box
i just want that if I click on a specific character in this textbox, this click pass that specific character to this function.